# Create scanning region to instruct user on barcode scanning app

Tags: ios, swift, barcode, region

I'm developing an barcode scanning app. I want to set a scanning region (draw a line or rectangle) to instruct user to place their barcode inside the scanning region. I use AVFoundation for the scanning engine.

This is the code to create scanning region to instruct user to place the barcode inside

```
var captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = captureMetadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes
            
let scanningRegion = UIView(frame: captureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest)
scanningRegion.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
scanningRegion.layer.borderWidth = 2
view.addSubview(scanningRegion)
view.bringSubview(toFront: scanningRegion)
```

I don't know why when I run the app not thing show up (suppose to have a rectangle with red border to catch user attention.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2)? It might help you understand what's going on

Comment: Thanks will have a look. Doubt the problem with my code KVO for NSSet